# Creating a column of match probabilities from hmni package python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame    
df = pd.DataFrame({'CEOThisYr': ['Douglas Davis', 'Doug Davis', 'James Taylor', 'Jane Smith'], ['CEOLastYr': 'Doug Davis', 'James Taylor', 'Jane Smith', 'Sarah Jones']})
```

My goal is to use the hmni package to create a new column with the match probability scores of each name across rows. My attempted code is:

```
import hmni
matcher = hmni.Matcher(model='latin')
df['MatchPercent'] = matcher.similarity(df['CEOThisYr'], df['CEOLastYr'])
```

That returns the error: TypeError: Only string comparison is supported in similarity method

I've tried converting both columns to string just to be sure but that still returns the same error. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

***Update****

Thanks to the helpful comment below, I was able to come up with

```
import hmni
matcher = hmni.Matcher(model='latin')
df['MatchPercent'] = df.apply(lambda x: matcher.similarity(x['CEOThisYr'], x['CEOLastYr']), axis=1)
```

I went from 9 seconds to process 1 row to processing approx 5000 rows per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [hmni's docs](https://pypi.org/project/hmni/), `similarity` accepts twos `str`s as its first and second arguments. You are trying to pass two `pandas.Series`, i.e., `df['CEOThisYr']` and `df['CEOLastYr']`. You could try using `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to apply `similarity` to each row.

```py
>>> import hmni
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'CEOThisYr': ['Douglas Davis', 'Doug Davis', 'James Taylor', 'Jane Smith'], 'CEOLastYr': ['Doug Davis', 'James Taylor', 'Jane Smith', 'Sarah Jones']})
>>> df
       CEOThisYr     CEOLastYr
0  Douglas Davis    Doug Davis
1     Doug Davis  James Taylor
2   James Taylor    Jane Smith
3     Jane Smith   Sarah Jones
>>>
>>> matcher = hmni.Matcher(model='latin')
>>> df['MatchPercent'] = df.apply(lambda x: matcher.similarity(x['CEOThisYr'], x['CEOLastYr']), axis=1)
>>> df
       CEOThisYr     CEOLastYr  MatchPercent
0  Douglas Davis    Doug Davis      0.922682
1     Doug Davis  James Taylor      0.000000
2   James Taylor    Jane Smith      0.000000
3     Jane Smith   Sarah Jones      0.000000
```

Comment: To make the process run faster, I defined the similarity function before running the lambda function. Otherwise it takes my machine 9 seconds to apply to 1 row whereas if the function is already defined, my machine can process 5000 rows per second on average (I had 1.3+ million rows!